Four Year Old Pushing and Positive Discipline Techniques
This isn't a major problem for us, but I'm curious to get a few perspectives on this issue. My wife and I have two boys, two and four, both close to two and four, and for the most part we try to use positive discipline techniques to correct their behavior. So far we don't really punish them, although we'll very occasionally raise our voice in a targeted way (usually only for the four year old at this point). We try to teach and mentor them into better behavior, rather than making them feel bad about things they've done.
I think, for the most part, this has been successful and we've seen real improvements in self regulation in the four year old. He's very independent, and I would call him mature for his age. The two year old is too young to see much difference.
However, occasionally the four year old will do something a little over the line like push younger brother completely unprompted, and in his last months at daycare he's really starting to test the educators. This is where the question comes in. A part of me thinks: this is all age appropriate for the most part, and he'll gradually grow out of it in the next few years. But he is becoming a little more brazen, and you can tell that he's becoming comfortable testing boundaries because there are no real repercussions to his behavior. For the most part he's well behaved, but when he wants to break a rule he'll break a rule.
So then that leads to the question: do we introduce some kind of mild deterrent to encourage him to stop doing things like pushing his brother, or other ridiculous / dangerous stuff. Something like no TV for the night. Would that kind of thing be age appropriate, or does his behavior come down to not having the ability to fully self regulate?

We don't currently have sibling dynamics to worry about, but we do have a four year old who enjoys a good bit of boundary testing! He's also usually a well behaved child, who has his moments!
We like to have the 'punishment' fit the crime. Hitting, or otherwise hurting one of us means that we remove ourselves from him temporarily. Saying something like "I don't want to stay near someone who hurts me". So he may end up having some "calming down time" in his room by himself, or I'll go and hide in my room. I feel the "natural consequence" of hurting our friends is that they don't want to play with you, and also I want to model that if one of his friends hurts him then he doesn't have to put up with it.
If something seems to be prompting the behaviour, e.g. what he's watching on TV at that moment, then that will also stop immediately. But generically saying "if you hit, then you don't watch TV later/tomorrow/for the rest of the week" is a bit more complicated for them to connect cause and effect, I like it to be more immediate.
He usually gets upset, he'll say sorry and accept a cuddle to help calm down eventually.

I'd be much more careful about just taking the TV away. The toddler may think that if he didn't tell his parents about things he saw on TV or didn't show his parents what shows he was watching, he would have been able to keep watching the TV when he wanted to. This could potentially encourage distrust or unhealthy secret-keeping.

You already have an excellent answer (which I upvoted), but I would like to elaborate a bit on a point or two. But first, is it normal? It's so normal that it's pretty surprising when it doesn't happen.

do we introduce some kind of mild deterrent to encourage him to stop doing things like pushing his brother, or other ridiculous / dangerous stuff.

Absolutely! But try very hard to make the deterrent/consequence fit the "crime". Sometimes it's not easy to think of an appropriate consequence right away. In that case, your child is old enough to understand that any significantly bad behavior (like hitting someone) can merit an immediate time out. I don't advocate for immediate time outs very often, but at this age, they aren't ready to understand another option (e.g. "I need some time to think about this, but there definitely will be  consequences to your behavior.") Time outs can be regarded as punitive (negative sense) but done calmly and wisely does no harm, imo.
As this seems to be a pattern you'll be dealing with for a while, please consider if you're doing enough emotional literacy building and empathy building. Having the ability to express the feelings a child has in a specific situation is the first step to managing those feelings in a non-destructive way. Having the ability to empathize with others is helpful in predicting which behaviors will cause others harm (physical or emotional), or recognizing the harm they may have caused and understanding that it's not the best way to deal with others.
We have lots of information on both emotional literacy and empathy building here on Parenting.SE.

As a parent who has recently gone through this phase (have 6yo), I found that a mix of making a plan beforehand (for common behaviours: if he does this, we do this) and also having a general purpose default option (anything else, we do timeout/etc)  has helped with having an immediate response to bad behaviour, and with generally the kiddo knowing what to expect.

We do a fair amount of emotional / empathy building, and I think he gets it to some degree. Although I find that my partner isn't always great at modelling empathy, and I sometimes wonder if that leads to a little more aggression than there could be. OTOH, I model gentleness and patience all the time, so I think they kind of sway between both behaviors.

@Cdn_Dev - I can find sources to support this assertion, but I'll just state it here: I think that any time parenting styles vary between partners (probably the rule rather than the exception), children do get mixed messages. However, I'm not sure that's inherently bad. Though it would go more smoothly if parents were in synch, I believe consistency and respect for the child as a person might be more important for smooth parent-child expectations. It was in my home; my kids responded to each parent as they were parented.

That makes sense, thank you. Yes sometimes I feel like I'm also modelling parenting for my partner (won't go into detail but there are issues). She generally knows that she should model good behavior, respect, etc etc. But often, in the heat of the moment, her actual execution is off. It's gotten much better over time, but still not perfect.

@Cdn_Dev - Oh, I've been there, I understand that. I tried to get my partner on board, but it never happened. So I just did the best I could, and it worked out ok for me. That was the best I could do. My kids understood that their parents had different strengths.
